# Converting codes to pdf with its outputs in Pycharm

Tags: python, pdf, pycharm, r-markdown, markdown

I am beginner for the python language and I am looking for an option like markdown in R. I mean, is there any availability for converting my codes to pdf with its outputs in PYCHARM like markdown does in R? I can do this in JupyterLab but I need to do this in Pycharm :( Thank you for answers :)

Comment: If you have the Professional version of PyCharm, you can work with Juptyer notebooks directly: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html

Comment: Oh, I can handle with thanks to jupyter notebook now. Thank you very much!